# Highlight menu item on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have a website. It has navigation section with some menu. It is a single page application.

The requirement is if we are in the home, or in any other section, it should highlight the respective menu. It should do so on scrolling to the required section.

In this sample website i'm going highlight menu item during smooth scroll. I have tried $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#menu' }) this one but couldn't help me

```js
*/


(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        
       /* Preloader */
  
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('.preloader').delay(800).fadeOut('slow');
        });
  
  
  
       /* Smooth Scroll */

        $('a.smoth-scroll').on("click", function (e) {
            var anchor = $(this);
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50
            }, 1000);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
  


       $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#menu' })

       /* Scroll Naviagation Background Change with Sticky Navigation */
   
        $(window).on('scroll', function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('.header-top-area').addClass('navigation-background');
            } else {
                $('.header-top-area').removeClass('navigation-background');
            }
        });
  
  
  
  
       /* Mobile Navigation Hide or Collapse on Click */
  
        $(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse.in', function (e) {
            if ($(e.target).is('a') && $(e.target).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle') {
                $(this).collapse('hide');
            }
        });
        $('body').scrollspy({
            target: '.navbar-collapse',
            offset: 195
        
   });
   
  
  
  
        /* Scroll To Top */
  
        $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 500) {
            $('.scroll-to-top').fadeIn();
         } else {
            $('.scroll-to-top').fadeOut();
         }
    });
 
 
     $('.scroll-to-top').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
    return false;
     });
  

        
        /* Tooltip */
         
         $(function () {
           $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
           })
     
   
        
        /* Ajaxchimp for Subscribe Form */
  
         $('#mc-form').ajaxChimp();
```

```css
/* Global Style */

body {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 24px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%
}

::selection {
    background-color: #f7639a;
    color: #ffffff;
}

::-moz-selection {
    background-color: #f7639a;
    color: #ffffff;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

a {
    color: #4c9cef;
}

a:hover,
a:active{
    background: pink;
}
a:focus {
    /*color: #f7639a;
    text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;*/
}

p {
    line-height: 28px;
}

b {
 font-weight: 600;
}

ul,
li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

fieldset {
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.no-padding {
    padding: 0
}

.pink-color {
 color: #f7639a !important;
}

.pink-color-bg {
 background-color: #f7639a !important;
}

.section-space-padding {
    padding: 100px 0px;
}

.section-title {
    text-align: center;
}

.section-title h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.section-title p {
    font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.bg-cover {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.pattern-bg {
 background: url(../images/bg/pattern-bg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat;
}

.grabbing {
 cursor: url(../images/owl-carousel/grabbing.png) 8 8, move;
}

.divider > i {
 color: #f7639a;
 font-size: 21px;
}

.divider {
 position: relative;
 width: 126px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: center;
}

.divider:after,
.divider:before {
 content: ' ';
 width: 43px;
 position: absolute;
 border-bottom: dotted 2px #ffffff;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -4px;
}

.divider:before {
 left: 0;
}

.divider:after {
 right: 0;
}

.divider.dark:after,
.divider.dark:before {
 border-color: #b2b2b2;
}

.button {
 border: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-family: inherit;
 font-size: 17px;
 color: inherit;
 background: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 20px 60px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-weight: 700;
 outline: none;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

.button:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}

.button-style {
 border: 3px solid #fff;
 color: #fff;
}

.button-style:hover,
.button-style:active,
.button-style:focus {
 color: #ffffff;
 background: #4c9cef;
}

.button-style-color-2:hover,
.button-style-color-2:active,
.button-style-color-2:focus {
 color: #ffffff;
 background: #f7639a !important;
}

.button-style-dark {
 border: 3px solid #000000;
 color: #000000;
}



/* Preloader */

.preloader {
    background: #F9F9F9;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.preloader p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 48%;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #333333;
}

.preloader:before, .preloader:after {
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 40%;
    background-color: #4c9cef;
    animation: squaremove 1s ease-in-out infinite;
    -webkit-animation: squaremove 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.preloader:after {
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #f7639a;
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

@keyframes squaremove {
  0%, 100%{
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,0) rotate(0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,0) rotate(0);
    -o-transform: translate(0,0) rotate(0);
    transform: translate(0,0) rotate(0);
  }

  25%{
    -webkit-transform: translate(40px,40px) rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: translate(40px,40px) rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: translate(40px,40px) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translate(40px,40px) rotate(45deg);
  }

  50%{
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,80px) rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px,80px) rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: translate(0px,80px) rotate(0deg);
    transform: translate(0px,80px) rotate(0deg);
  }

  75%{
    -webkit-transform: translate(-40px,40px) rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: translate(-40px,40px) rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: translate(-40px,40px) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translate(-40px,40px) rotate(45deg);
  }
}



/* Home Section and Navigation Menu */

.home-section {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.table {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.table a {
 color: #ffffff;
}

.table > tbody > tr > td {
 padding: 15px;
 border: 3px solid #e4e4e4;
}

.table tr > td {
 padding: 11px 13px;
}

tr:nth-child(1) > td {
 border-top:0px;
}

tr > td:nth-child(1){
 background-color: #ffffff;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #888888;
 width: 140px;
}

tr > td:nth-child(2) {
 font-weight: 500;
 color: #ffffff;
 background: #4c9cef;
}

.header-top-area {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.logo {
    padding-top: 28px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.logo a {
    display: block;
    color: #333333;
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #f7639a;
    width: 92px;
}

.navigation-menu .navbar-nav li a {
    color: #333333;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 30px 15px;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.navigation-menu .navbar-nav li a:hover {
    background: none;
    color: #f7639a;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.nav li a:focus,
.nav li a:hover {
    background: none;
    color: #4c9cef;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.navbar {
    margin: 0;
}

.navigation-background {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    background: #4c9cef;
}

.navigation-background .logo {
    padding-top: 18px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.navigation-background .logo a {
 color: #ffffff;
}

.navigation-background .navigation-menu .navbar-nav li a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
}

.navigation-background .navigation-menu .navbar-nav li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}







/* Scroll To Top */

.scroll-to-top {
    background-color: #4c9cef;
    display: none;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 25px;
 border-radius: 100%;
    line-height: 67px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: 30px;
    z-index: 999;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(90, 91, 95, 0.15);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.scroll-to-top:hover,
.scroll-to-top:focus {
    background-color: #f7639a;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 16px 22px 0px rgba(90, 91, 95, 0.3);
}



/* Responsive */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
 .experience-circle i {
  font-size: 30px;
 }
 
 .experience-content{
  margin-left: 75px;
 }
 
 .experience-content:after, 
 .experience-content:before {
  top: 30%;
 }
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .navigation-menu .navbar-nav li a {
        padding: 30px 11px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    
 .navigation-background .navigation-menu .navbar-nav li a {
        padding: 30px 11px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
 
 .navigation-background .logo {
  padding-top: 28px;
 }
 
 .margin-left-setting {
  margin-left: 0px !important;
 }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
     .call-to-action h2 {
        font-size: 20px;
  }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
        background: #f7639a;
    }
    
 .navigation-background .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
        background: #ffffff;
    }
    
 .navbar-toggle {
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-top: -30px;
    }
    
 .navbar {
        min-height: 0px;
    }
    
 .navigation-menu .navbar-nav li a {
        padding: 11px 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
    }
    
 .navigation-menu .navbar-nav li a:hover {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    
 .navigation-background .navigation-menu .navbar-nav li a:hover {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    
 .navigation-background .navigation-menu .navbar-nav li a {
        padding: 11px 15px;
    }
    
 .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse,
    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
        max-height: 420px;
    }
    
 .navbar-toggle {
        margin-top: -30px;
    }
    
 .navbar-collapse {
        background: #4c9cef;
    }
    
 .navigation-background .navbar-collapse {
        background: #4c9cef;
    }
    
 .section-title h2 {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    
 .testimonial-word {
        padding: 0;
    }
    
 .testimonial-carousel-list {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
    
 .call-to-action h2 {
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 35px;
 }
    
 .contact-us-detail {
        left: 39%;
    }
    
 .owl-prev {
        left: 5px;
    }
    
 .owl-next {
        right: 5px;
    }
    
 .scroll-to-top {
        width: 45px !important;
        height: 45px !important;
        font-size: 20px !important;
        line-height: 52px !important;
        right: 8px !important;
        bottom: 15px !important;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 555px) {
 .social-icon li a {
         width: 40px;
         height: 40px;
         line-height: 44px;
         font-size: 16px;
      }
   
     .section-title h2 {
         font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: 500;
       }
  
      .section-title p {
         font-weight: 300;
         font-size: 12px;
      }
   
   .statistics-content > h5 {
        font-size: 20px;
      }
   
      .statistics-content > span {
        font-size: 10px;
      }
   
      .statistics-icon {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
   
      .services-section hr {
          width: 35px;
      }
   
   .services-section h3 {
          font-size: 12px;
      }

      .services-section .services-detail {
          width: 180px;
          height: 180px;
      }

      .services-section .services-detail i {
          font-size: 30px;
          margin-top: 45px;
      }
   
      .owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div {
          padding: 6px 10px;
          width: 40px;
          height: 40px;
          line-height: 36px;
    font-size: 8px;
       }
    
      .contact-us-detail {
          left: 30%;
       }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .experience {
  margin-left: 0px;
  border: 0px;
 }
 
 .experience-circle {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: static;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
 
 .experience-content {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
 }
 
 .experience-content:after, 
 .experience-content:before {
  display: none;
 }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 449px) {
    .button {
     font-size: 13px;
     padding: 14px 28px;
     font-weight: 600;
    }
    
    .contact-us-detail {
          left: 25%;
       }
}



/* Useful Classes */


/* Spacing ( with Margin and Padding ) */

/* Margin */

.margin-0 {
 margin: 0px !important;
}

/* Margin Top */

.margin-top-0 {
 margin-top: 0px !important;
}

.margin-top-10 {
 margin-top: 10px !important;
}

.margin-top-20 {
 margin-top: 20px !important;
}

.margin-top-30 {
 margin-top: 30px !important;
}

.margin-top-40 {
 margin-top: 40px !important;
}

.margin-top-50 {
 margin-top: 50px !important;
}

.margin-top-60 {
 margin-top: 60px !important;
}

.margin-top-70 {
 margin-top: 70px !important;
}

.margin-top-80 {
 margin-top: 80px !important;
}

.margin-top-90 {
 margin-top: 90px !important;
}

.margin-top-100 {
 margin-top: 100px !important;
}

.margin-top-120 {
 margin-top: 120px !important;
}

.margin-top-150 {
 margin-top: 150px !important;
}

.margin-top-200 {
 margin-top: 200px !important;
}


/* Margin Bottom */

.margin-bottom-0 {
 margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.margin-bottom-10 {
 margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.margin-bottom-20 {
 margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.margin-bottom-30 {
 margin-bottom: 30px !important;
}

.margin-bottom-40 {
 margin-bottom: 40px !important;
}

.margin-bottom-50 {
 margin-bottom: 50px !important;
}

.margin-bottom-60 {
 margin-bottom: 60px !important;
}

.margin-bottom-70 {
 margin-bottom: 70px !important;
}

.margin-bottom-80 {
 margin-bottom: 80px !important;
}

.margin-bottom-90 {
 margin-bottom: 90px !important;
}

.margin-bottom-100 {
 margin-bottom: 100px !important;
}

.margin-bottom-120 {
 margin-bottom: 120px !important;
}

.margin-bottom-150 {
 margin-bottom: 150px !important;
}

.margin-bottom-200 {
 margin-bottom: 200px !important;
}



/* Padding */

.padding-0 {
 padding: 0px !important;
}


/* Padding Top */

.padding-top-0 {
 padding-top: 0px !important;
}

.padding-top-10 {
 padding-top: 10px !important;
}

.padding-top-20 {
 padding-top: 20px !important;
}

.padding-top-30 {
 padding-top: 30px !important;
}

.padding-top-40 {
 padding-top: 40px !important;
}

.padding-top-50 {
 padding-top: 50px !important;
}

.padding-top-60 {
 padding-top: 60px !important;
}

.padding-top-70 {
 padding-top: 70px !important;
}

.padding-top-80 {
 padding-top: 80px !important;
}

.padding-top-90 {
 padding-top: 90px !important;
}

.padding-top-100 {
 padding-top: 100px !important;
}

.padding-top-120 {
 padding-top: 120px !important;
}

.padding-top-150 {
 padding-top: 150px !important;
}

.padding-top-200 {
 padding-top: 200px !important;
}


/* Padding Bottom */

.padding-bottom-0 {
 padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.padding-bottom-10 {
 padding-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.padding-bottom-20 {
 padding-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.padding-bottom-30 {
 padding-bottom: 30px !important;
}

.padding-bottom-40 {
 padding-bottom: 40px !important;
}

.padding-bottom-50 {
 padding-bottom: 50px !important;
}

.padding-bottom-60 {
 padding-bottom: 60px !important;
}

.padding-bottom-70 {
 padding-bottom: 70px !important;
}

.padding-bottom-80 {
 padding-bottom: 80px !important;
}

.padding-bottom-90 {
 padding-bottom: 90px !important;
}

.padding-bottom-100 {
 padding-bottom: 100px !important;
}

.padding-bottom-120 {
 padding-bottom: 120px !important;
}

.padding-bottom-150 {
 padding-bottom: 150px !important;
}

.padding-bottom-200 {
 padding-bottom: 200px !important;
}



/* Colors */

.color-1 {
 color: #f306a0;
}

.color-2 {
 color: #d60bfb;
}

.color-3 {
 color: #d8be10;
}

.color-4 {
 color: #0fd28a;
}

.color-5 {
 color: #f97400;
}

.color-6 {
 color: #08a6f3;
}



/* Background Color */

.bg-color-1 {
 background-color: #f306a0;
}

.bg-color-2 {
 background-color: #d60bfb;
}

.bg-color-3 {
 background-color: #d8be10;
}

.bg-color-4 {
 background-color: #0fd28a;
}

.bg-color-5 {
 background-color: #f97400;
}

.bg-color-6 {
 background-color: #08a6f3;
}



/* Tooltip Styles */

.tooltip-inner {
 font-style: italic;
 padding: 10px 12px;
 min-width: 150px;
 width: 100%;
}

.tooltip.top {
 margin-top:-15px;
}

.tooltip.bottom {
 margin-top:15px;
 bottom: auto;
 left: auto;
 right: auto;
}

.tooltip.left {
 margin-right:15px;
}

.tooltip.right {
 margin-left:15px;
}

.tooltip-color .tooltip-inner {
 color: #fff;
}



/* UiPasta Credit */

.uipasta-credit {
 color: #333333;
 text-align: center;
}

.uipasta-credit a {
 color: #4c9cef;
 font-weight: 600;
}

.uipasta-credit a:hover {
 color: #f7639a;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-top-area">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a href="index-2.html">WebRes</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <div class="navigation-menu">
                            <div class="navbar">
                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div id="menu" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                        <li class="active"><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#home">Home <div class="ripple-wrapper"></div></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#testimonials">Testimonial</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#services">services</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a class="smoth-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[Here is the image of sample where I need to highlight menu during scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W10ib.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every page you have, assign a variable for example in your Home.php

at the top of the page

```
<?php $page = "home" ?>
```

then in your navigation/toolbar

```
<li class=" <?php if($page == "home"){echo "active";}?> "> Home </li>
```

and in your css file you can customize whatever style you want with the active